# Google mobile sitemap alternate links, issue with XHTML

Tags: xml, xhtml, sitemap

I am trying to set up the following [configuration](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls?hl=en).

But when I try to validate my sitemap XML with validator (validome.org), I get the following error:
*The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'xhtml:link'.*

Test sitemap I tried to validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"              
        xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd
                            http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd">
   <url> 
        <loc>http://mobile.example.com/article100.html</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="nofollow" href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/" /> 
   </url> 
</urlset>
```

I have tried changing schemas, and namespaces, but no luck so far.
Anyone could determine the problem here?

Comment: Some related solutions I've tried, but with no success:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798979/xsd-for-sitemap-with-hreflang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using these schemas with the xhtml:link alternate

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<url>

<loc>http://www.example.com/mypage.html</loc>

<xhtml:link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://mobile.example.com/mypage.html" />

<lastmod>20015-04-01</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>

</url>
```

Comment: If it don't work, try to update all the full qualified links to https. It worked for me